# Is each Parovichenko compact space homeomorphic to the remainder of a soft compactification of $\mathbb N$?

Tags: set-theory, gn.general-topology, compactifications, stone-cech-compactification

**Definition 1.** A compactification $c\mathbb N$ of the discrete space $\mathbb N$ is called *soft* if for any disjoint sets $A,B\subset\mathbb N$ with $\bar A\cap\bar B\ne\emptyset$ there exists a homeomorphism $h:c\mathbb N\to c\mathbb N$ such that $h(x)=x$ for all $x\in c\mathbb N\setminus\mathbb N$ and the set $\{x\in A:h(x)\in B\}$ is infinite.

**Definition 2.** A compact Hausdorff space $X$ is called *Parovichenko* (resp. *soft Parovichenko*) if $X$ is homeomorphic to the remainder $c\mathbb N\setminus\mathbb N$ of some (soft) compactification $c\mathbb N$ of $\mathbb N$?

**Remark 1.** By a classical Parovichenko Theorem, each compact Hausdorff space of weight $\le\aleph_1$ is Parovichenko.  Hence, under CH a compact Hausdorff space is Parovichenko if and only if it has weight $\le\mathfrak c$. By a result of Przymusinski, each perfectly normal compact space is Parovichenko. On the other hand, Bell constructed an consistent example of a first-countable compact Hausdorff space, which is not Parovichenko. More information and references on Parovichenko spaces can be found in [this survey of Hart and van Mill](https://fa.its.tudelft.nl/~hart/37/publications/the_papers/open_problems_on_betaN.pdf) (see $\S$3.10),

> **Problem 1.** Is each Parovichenko compact space soft Parovichenko?

**Remark 2.** The Stone-Cech compactification $\beta\mathbb N$ of $\mathbb N$ is soft, but there are [simple examples](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/309458/is-each-compactification-of-mathbb-n-soft) of compactifications which are not soft. A compactification $c\mathbb N$ of $\mathbb N$ is soft if for any disjoint sets $A,B\subset\mathbb N$ with $\bar A\cap\bar B\ne\emptyset$ there are sequences $\{a_n\}_{n\in\omega}\subset A$ and $\{b_n\}_{n\in\omega}\subset B$ that converge to the same point $x\in\bar A\cap\bar B$. This implies that a compactification $c\mathbb N$ is soft if the space $c\mathbb N$ is Frechet-Urysohn or has sequential square. This also implies that *each first-countable Parovichenko space is soft Parovichenko* (more generally, *a Parovichenko space $X$ is soft Parovichenko if each point $x\in X$ has a neighborhood base of cardinality $<\mathfrak p$*).

> **Problem 2.** Is each (Frechet-Urysohn) sequential Parovichenko space soft Parovichenko?

The following concrete version of Problem 1 describes an example of a Parovichenko space for which we do not know if it is soft Parovichenko.

> **Problem 3.** Let $X$ be a compact space that can be written as the union $X=A\cup B$ where $A$ is homeomorphic to $\beta\mathbb N\setminus\mathbb N$, $B$ is homeomorphic to the Cantor cube $\{0,1\}^\omega$ and $A\cap B\ne\emptyset$. Is the space $X$ soft Parovichenko?

Comment: Is there a characterization of non-(either soft or not) Parovichenko compacts?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე I added (to my question) some known information about (soft) Parovichenko spaces.

Comment: For what it's worth: every compactification with the ordinal $\omega_1+1$ as its remainder is soft.

Comment: I read a definition of "Parovichenko space" as: a Stone space $X$ with weight $\mathbf{c}$, no isolated point and in which every nonempty countable intersection of open subsets has nonempty interior. (Under CH this characterizes $\beta\mathbf{N}\smallsetminus\mathbf{N}$ up to homeomorphism.) Is this related?

Comment: @YCor No, "your" Parovichenko space is different than "mine".

Comment: Actually it's not "my" definition: it's used in a 1978 Proc AMS paper of van Douwen and van Mill, in a Dow paper in Topol. Appl. 1985, in a 2012 paper of Glasner and Gutman, etc, and even has a Wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parovicenko_space.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a partial answer: the [Continuum Hypothesis implies that all Parovichenko spaces are soft-Parovichenko](http://fa.its.tudelft.nl/~hart/37/publications/the_papers/soft-compactifications.pdf); the proof is a bit long, so I put it in a PDF-file on my website.

Also, I retract my claim in the comments that all compactifications with $\omega_1+1$ as a remainder are soft. It is true, in ZFC, that $\omega_1+1$ is soft-Parovichenko but "all compactifications with remainder $\omega_1+1$ are soft" is equivalent to $\mathfrak{t}>\omega_1$.

Added 2018-11-12: The note linked to above now contains a, consistent, example of a Parovichenko space that is not soft-Parovichenko. The example is the ordered space $\omega_1+1+\omega_1^\ast$.

Comment: Thank you for this partial solution. Indeed, the construction written in the pdf-file is rather complicated. Is it indeed requires the full strenth of CH, or something weaker like $\mathfrak t=\mathfrak c$?

Comment: All I can say about CH is that it appears to be needed in this proof: it needs countable initial segments and is the density of $X$ is equal to continuum then you expect to have to take care of continuum many pairs. The proof can be simplified a bit and I will do that later.

Comment: There is now a consistent counterexample, see the answer.

Comment: Thank you. But It would be helpful to remind what does the principle (NT) says exactly.

Comment: I have added the formulation to the note.

Comment: Thank you. Please correct $b\in \mathcal B$ to $B\in\mathcal B$ in the last but one line on page 4. You writes that (NT) is consistent with $\mathfrak c=\mathfrak b=\aleph_2$. Is it true that (NT) follows from $\mathfrak p>\aleph_1$?

Comment: The application of (NT) to this example shows that it implies $\mathfrak{t}=\aleph_1$: the $L_\alpha$ determine a tower on $C_L$. Alan proved the consistency directly by iterated forcing (finite support, $\sigma$-centered).

Comment: Alan Dow's paper is open access: https://cms.math.ca/10.4153/CMB-1997-050-0