# A ``1-soft'' improvement of the Parovichenko theorem

Tags: set-theory, gn.general-topology, compactifications

This is a ``1-soft'' modification of [this problem](https://mathoverflow.net/q/309583/61536). We start with the necessary definitions.

**Definition 1.** A compactification $c\mathbb N$ of the discrete space $\mathbb N$ is called *1-soft* if for any subset $A\subset\mathbb N$ with $\overline{A}\cap\overline{\mathbb N\setminus A}\ne\emptyset$ there exists a homeomorphism $h:c\mathbb N\to c\mathbb N$ such that $h(x)=x$ for all $x\in c\mathbb N\setminus\mathbb N$ and the set $\{x\in A:h(x)\notin A\}$ is infinite.

**Definition 2.** A compactification $c\mathbb N$ of the discrete space $\mathbb N$ is called *2-soft* if for any disjoint sets $A,B\subset\mathbb N$ with $\bar A\cap\bar B\ne\emptyset$ there exists a homeomorphism $h:c\mathbb N\to c\mathbb N$ such that $h(x)=x$ for all $x\in c\mathbb N\setminus\mathbb N$ and the set $\{x\in A:h(x)\in B\}$ is infinite.

Before the formulation of a question, let us recall some known results.

**Theorem ([Parovichenko](https://fa.its.tudelft.nl/%7Ehart/37/publications/the_papers/open_problems_on_betaN.pdf)).** Each compact Hausdorff space $K$ of weight $\le\omega_1$ is homeomorphic to the remainder $c\mathbb N\setminus \mathbb N$ of some compactification $c\mathbb N$ of $\mathbb N$.

**Theorem ([Hart](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1811.03912.pdf)).** Under CH, each compact Hausdorff space $K$ of weight $\le\omega_1$ is homeomorphic to the remainder of a 2-soft compactification of $\mathbb N$.

**Example ([Dow](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1811.03912.pdf)).** Under (NT) the compact space $K=\omega_1+1+\omega_1^*$ is not homeomorphic to the remainder of a 2-soft compactification of $\mathbb N$.

> **Question 1.** Is the compact space $K=\omega_1+1+\omega_1^*$ homeomorphic to the remainder of a 1-soft compactification of $\mathbb N$?
>
> **Question 2.** Is each compact Hausdorff space of weight $\le\omega_1$ homeomorphic to the remainder of a 1-soft compactification of $\mathbb N$?

---

**Added in Edit.** The answer to Question 1 is affirmative. So, only Question 2 remains open.

Comment: I guess the $B$ in the definition of $1$-soft should be $A$?

Comment: Yes, exactly! Thank you (I am glad that you noticed this question).

Comment: @KPHart I have just asked another set-theoretic question (https://mathoverflow.net/q/351555/61536) related to Question 1.

Comment: Could you include the construction for 1?

Comment: @KPHart I added a link to the paper in arXiv.